# How to use Expanded with e.g. GestureDetector on path from Column to Expanded

Tags: flutter

I currently create an editor, which allows to insert new items at certain places in a two dimensional plane.

The editor places items on the screen and wraps them in [GestureDetector()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) or [DragTarget()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DragTarget-class.html) to allow to drop in new editor items.

Therefore, structures like this appear often, to show editable items in a property inspector widget, if the user clicks on the [Expanded()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) Widgets area:

```
   Column(
      children: [
        DragTarget(
          builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
            return Expanded(
              child: Text( 'X' ),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    )
```

This, as well as GestureDetector(), generates this render error:

> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The ParentDataWidget [Expanded(flex: 1)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) wants to apply ParentData of
> type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept
> ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.
>
> Usually, this means that the [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget has the wrong ancestor
> RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly
> inside Flex widgets. The offending Expanded is currently placed inside
> a MetaData widget.

If I remove the DragTarget(), the tree renders fine:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
          child: Text( 'X' ),
        )
  ],
)
```

**Q How to make an [Expanded()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) a [DragTarget()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DragTarget-class.html) or a [GestureDetector()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) child?**

Needless to note, that the problem appears with any compile target.

Since the editor allows to drop widget like Column, Card etc., I need a generic solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> Using an Expanded widget makes a child of a Row, Column, or Flex
> expand to fill the available space along the main axis (e.g.,
> horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column).

That means you can only use the `Expanded` widget as direct child of a `Row`, `Column` or `Flex`. That is also why your snippet works without the `DragTarget` since in that case the `Expanded` is a direct child of your `Column`.

To fix your problem you could do something like this:

```
   Column(
      children: [
        DragTarget(
          builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                 Expanded(child: Text( 'X' ))
              ]
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    )
```

You could also wrap your `DragTarget` into an `Expanded` widget. It's hard to help you exactly without more information. But both ways atleast wont return an error.