# Flutter: "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget" exception when wrapping an Expanded in a GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, exception, row, gesturedetector, expanded

*Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to Flutter, so I am not fully clear on some of the constraints related to what widget "can" go into which other widget, so this may be a simple mistake... I appreciate everyone's patience and guidance!*

Hi everyone! :)

I'll start with the change that leads to the error:

```
GestureDetector(
  child: Expanded(
    child: Text(
      displayTime ? "Some text" : "Some other text"
      style: textStyle),
    ),
   onTap: () { // No code yet here 
   },
),
```

With the above code, I get the "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget" exception, right after wrapping the Expanded in a GestureDetector. If I remove the GestureDetector, the app works fine.

The widget this sits in is in the following tree:
[Widget Tree of the widget where the GestureDetector sits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIbYV.png)

This Widget, itself, sits in the following tree (TaskBubble):
[View of where the problematic widget sits in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMmxT.png)

Now, I could always work around this and find another way to get that `onTap()`, but I'd rather understand the issue to fix it for good.

I've tried the following:

1. Removing the GestureDetector - which removes the exception
2. Removing the Expanded - and it works, but then I'm not getting the layout I want - i.e. a Text field expanding between two other widgets in a row
3. Understanding whether my Widget tree choices are correct (i.e., roughly: ListView, Row, Widget, Row, GestureDetector, Expanded tree) - but I can't find anything conclusive at this point.

Thanks for the support!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I guess that posting the question was sufficient to find a solution. A suggested article right under my question was:
[How to use Expanded with e.g. GestureDetector on path from Column to Expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75349027/how-to-use-expanded-with-e-g-gesturedetector-on-path-from-column-to-expanded?rq=2)

So the problem was that **Expanded needs to be a direct child of the Row**. Putting the GestureDetector on the Text widget did the trick:

```
Expanded(
  child: GestureDetector(
    child: Text(
      displayTime ? "Text" : "Other text"
      style: ts),
    onTap: () {},
  ),
),
```

Hopefully my post and self answer will help someone else.

Thanks!